# If this variant of Subset Product remains NP-complete, what other inputs could give me exponential time?

Tags: time-complexity, np-complete, subset-product

Given $N$ a whole number and a set $S$ of divisors of N, where no repetition is allowed. Decide if there is a combination of divisors with a product equal to $N$.

- Remove non-divisors from $S$.
- Remove duplicates from S by using set() in python.
- Treat $S$ as list of non-duplicates and sort from smallest to largest. This is a requirement to finding the maximum combination size.
- Check each divisor in $S$ sequentially multiply each number until <= $N$, this will give us the maximum combination size.

Let $S$ = {$d_1$,$d_2$...$d_n$} our sorted list of divisors with no duplicates

```
    Initialize maxCombinationSize = 0
     For each divisor d_i in S
            If divisor_product multiplied by divisor is less than or equal to N
                  Increment max_combination_size by 1
                  Update divisor_product by multiplying it with divisor
            else:
                exit loop
```

Special Cases

- Check if the product of all elements in $S$ equals $N$, if so output
  $True$.
- Check if the product of all elements in $S$ is less than $N$, if so
  output $False$.
- Check for substring Products, Considering all possible contiguous subsequences of S requires nested loops, result in $|S|^2$ time. If solution found output $True$

We know it's impossible to have a solution of combination size larger than the maximum as the product of that combination will exceed $N$.

We do all combinations of size 1 up to $maxCombinationSize$
if the total product of that combination = $N$ output $True$

If all combinations up to the maximum_combination_size have been exhausted and no solution is found, output $false$

Consider the case where $N$ is a power of $2$,

- Maximum number of divisors of 2^119 with product <= 2^119:
- $(15, [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192,
     16384])$
- Maximum number of divisors of 2^120 with product <= 2^120:
- $(16, [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192,
     16384, 32768])$

Notice, that the maximum number of divisors appears to grow logarithmically in the size of N. The size of $N$ is the exponent for base-2. Maybe, I'm wrong and this could be sqrt(N) as in the size of N.

That would mean the maximum combination size seems to grow very slowly. There may be more non-trivial inputs to look for, if this variant remains NP-complete as that would imply an efficient algorithm for Subset Product.

What non-trivial inputs would there be that would allow exponential time?

Comment: If $N$ = 0, simply look for zero in S efficently.

Comment: Sorting the list is required for correctness of the algorithm.

Comment: We must also consider input S. Is it exponential in both inputs?

Comment: Or how should I say, both inputs would be considered for the overall time complexity as if they were one?